# Java set breakpoints programmatically

Tags: java, breakpoints

Is there any way to programmatically set breakpoints in Java?

Assume you have the filename with the source code line:

```
Test.java:123
```

How this can be done?

Comment: This question has been asked before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856388/setting-breakpoints-in-java).

Comment: Yes, but I asked for an example how programatically to do that. There are given only explanations which I couldn't figure out how to apply concretely.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse IDE does not allow you to set a breakpoint from your java code.

However, it does allow you to set *conditional breakpoints*.  With a conditional breakpoint, you can tell Eclipse to only break on a line after some Java expression evaluates to true.  You can only tell it to break after some number of iterations.  These modes should suffice for almost every usecase.

To enable a conditional breakpoint, right-click on a breakpoint and go to "Breakpoint properties".

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days of VisualAge Jave, I did this with

```
DebugSupport.halt()
```

This is something that would have to be supported by the IDE, and would break if the IDE dependencies were not present. As fas I know there are no IDEs today that support this.

Comment: Up vote for VisualAge goodness, things like this make me miss Smalltalk so much!

Answer (score 0):

- I had the same problem but with 10000 files of java which i wanted to search for some string and put breakpoints based on that search.
- You can generate xml file containing all breakpoints you need.
- How to get that xml file structure?? simply go to debug mode --> right click ->Export breakpoints->then save the file anywhere.open that file and see how it is constructed.
- what i did that i searched all the files line by line and generated that xml file and imported it to eclipse.

-You may wonder that how you can loop through 10000 file line by line as it will take a lot of time,you are right but what i did to overcome this is by inserting all lines into indexed field on mysql db.

-I know your case is not that complex but i hope it gives you an idea.you may come with something even better.

Answer (score 0):

Most debuggers will let you break on an exception, so just create your own BreakpointException class, throw and immediately catch it.  Have the debugger pause only on BreakpointException.