# programmatically disable breakpoints

Tags: java, debugging

I am facing the following problem: I have some threads which starts like this:

> 1. Thread x starts
> 2. Thread x runs some calls
> 3. At this point thread x+1 is created (same code as x)
> 4. Thread x+1 runs some calls
> 5. .......
> 6. Thread x+1 exits
> 7. Thread x runs some code and exits

When I place a breakpoint in the code it stops both thread `x` and `x+1`, I am looking for an automatic way to make the debugger stop only at the breakpoint of the first thread that ran the code.

I am familiar with adding breakpoints in `C` so I guess there is a way to manipulate breakpoints in `Java` and hopefully there is someway to disable them (maybe disable the Java equivalent of the C debug signal).

I have tried writing an eclipse plugin that would do it but I hope there is an easier way, currently that's not working too good and also I want it to be more agnostic to the IDE.

any suggestions?

Comment: does Eclipse offer conditional breakpoints which will cause a break only if the condition is true?  I know that Visual Studio has this and would expect that Eclipse does as well.

Comment: @RichardChambers Hi, I am looking for a way to disable the other breakpoints automatically conditional breakpoints are available in eclipse but they does not suite my needs.

Comment: When you say programmatically, you mean an external program running separately or a self-mutating program setting and unsetting its own breakpoints?

Comment: @eis self mutating, even instrumentation comes into account if it may help

Comment: not sure what you mean by other breakpoints. the way I have handled something like this in the past is to have a variable that indicates which thread is running and to have a conditional breakpoint that does a test for the variable to have a specific value. then when the thread I want to see hits the conditional breakpoint and the condition is true, execution stops.

Comment: there is standard debugging api in JVM, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/861688/365237) for more details. However that is more about external programs - I don't know if any program can do it to itself.